Schur cover of alternating groups
Wilson's book "The finite simple groups" gives (in section 2.7) a description of the double cover of the alternating groups. First, one constructs a double cover $2S_n$ of the symmetric group $S_n$. By definition, a permutation $\pi$ has two lifts to $2S_n$, denoted by $+\pi$ and $-\pi$. Elements of $2S_n$ will be denoted by bracket notation as opposed to parentheses, i.e. $\pm[a_1,\ldots,a_k]$ are the lifts of the $k$-cycle $(a_1,\ldots,a_k)\in S_n$. He then defines multiplication in $2S_n$ by:

$[i,j]^{\pm\pi} = -[i^\pi,j^\pi]$, where $\pi$ is an odd permutation
A $k$-cycle can be written as $[a_1,\ldots,a_k] = [a_1,a_2][a_1,a_3],\cdots[a_1,a_k]$
A general element of $2S_n$ is a product of disjoint cycles

Then he says that you must be careful not to permute the cycles, or start a cycle at a different point.
His description is a bit confusing to me, mostly because he doesn't completely specify how to put elements of $2S_n$ into a ``canonical form''. I want to be certain that I'm understanding it correctly. Here are some questions:
(a) How do minus signs work when you multiply? For example, is $(-\pi)(-\sigma) = \pi\sigma$? (I would guess this is the case, as negation should presumably be viewed as multiplication by the nontrivial central element).
(b) What exactly is the difference between $[a_1,\ldots,a_k]$ and $[a_{k-i},\ldots,a_k,a_1,\ldots,a_{i-1}]$? (When are they the same?)
(c) Do disjoint cycles still commute in $2S_n$? (i.e., is $[1,2][3,4] = [3,4][1,2]$)? (In example 2.11, he shows that $[1,2][3,4] = -[3,4][1,2]$, but this doesn't answer the question)
(d) Are there other references for a similar "concrete" description of $2S_n$ that is more precise?

The standard permutation map of $S_n$ gives a homomorphism to $O(n)$ when thought of as matrices, and $A_n = S_n \cap SO(n)$. $SO(n)$ has a double cover $Spin(n)$, and the double cover of $A_n$ is the pullback to this double cover I believe.  $Pin(n)$ has a description in terms of Clifford algebras, as generated by preimage of reflections, so maybe one can get a “concrete” description out of that.

Don't you answer question (c) yourself? $[3,4][1,2]\neq - [3,4][1,2]$, as they differ by $-1$, the nontrivial element in the kernel of the map down to $S_n$.

One could ask, e.g., about the smallest permutation representation of this central extension of the symmetric (or alternating) group.

If you continue to the end of Section 2.7.2, there are actually two different double covers of $S_n$ (abstractly this comes from the fact that $S_n$ is not perfect, both of these double covers restrict to the same one on $A_n$.)
$2S_n^+$ is characterized by the rules you copied, plus $[i,j]^2=1$, while $2S_n^-$ has $[i,j]^2=-1$ instead.
To answer your questions:
(a): either of the double covers $2S_n^\pm$ fits into a central extension
$$
1 \to \{\pm 1\} \to 2S_n^\pm \to S_n \to 1,
$$
so yes, $-[a_1,\ldots,a_k]$ is just notation for $(-1)\cdot [a_1,\ldots,a_k]$, and the element $(-1)$ commutes with everything.
(b): They have the same image in $S_n$, so they are equal or differ by $-1$. To determine which, observe that a more general form of the first property holds, where
$$
[a_1,\ldots,a_k]^\pi = ([a_1,a_2] \cdots [a_1,a_k])^\pi = \operatorname{sgn}(\pi)^{k-1} [a_1^\pi,a_2^\pi]\cdots [a_1^\pi,a_k^\pi] = \operatorname{sgn}(\pi)^{k-1}[a_1^\pi,\ldots,a_k^\pi].
$$
In this case, you can take $\pi$ itself to be a lift of the permutation $(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_k)^{k-i-1}$, so $[a_1,\ldots,a_k]$ and $[a_{k-i},\ldots,a_k,a_1,\ldots,a_{i-1}]$ differ by the sign $(-1)^{(k-1)(k-i-1)}$, I think.
(c): If $[a_1,\ldots,a_k]$ and $[b_1,\ldots,b_l]$ are disjoint, we have
$$
[a_1,\ldots,a_k]^{[b_1,\ldots,b_l]} = \operatorname{sgn}((b_1,\ldots,b_l))^{k-1} [a_1,\ldots,a_k] = (-1)^{(l-1)(k-1)} [a_1,\ldots,a_k],
$$
by the same observation as in the previous discussion. So pairs of disjoint odd cycles anticommute.
Multiplying elements
To understand the multiplication better, let us first solve the following problem: Given a sequence of transpositions $[i,j]$ which multiply to the trivial permutation in $S_n$, how can we find their product in $2S_n^{\pm}$? This product is an element of $\{\pm 1\}$, i.e. a single sign.
Starting with $\prod_i [a_i,b_i]$ with the property that their product is trivial in $S_n$, trace how the element $1\in \{1,\ldots,n\}$ gets moved, and mark all transpositions that contribute to this. For example, from left to right, there might be a bunch of transpositions that do not move $1$, then a $[1,3]$, then a bunch of transpositions that do not move $3$, then say $[3,2]$, then a bunch of transpositions that do not move $2$, and finally a $[2,1]$, followed by a bunch of transpositions that do not move $1$.
We now perform the following move: Find the first marked transposition, say $[1,i]$ (otherwise rewrite $[i,1]=-[1,i]$), and let $[k,l]$ be the transposition immediately following it.

If $[k,l]$ is unmarked, it means it does not contain $i$. We may use $[1,i][k,l] = [k,l]^{[1,i]} [1,i]$ to rewrite our sequence, where the first transposition now does not contain $1$, so it is still unmarked. So now the first marked transposition occurs further to the right.
If they are both marked, either $k=i$ or $l=i$. Using $[k,l]=-[l,k]$, we may assume $l=i$. If we have $k=1$, then $[1,i][1,i] = \pm 1$ depending on whether we are in $2S_n^+$ or $2S_n^-$, and we may rewrite our sequence with two fewer transpositions. Otherwise, we have $[1,i][k,i] = -[k,1][1,i] = [k,i][k,1]$, and now again the first marked transposition occurs one further to the right.

Iterating this, we may rewrite our whole sequence by one without marked transpositions, i.e. $1$ does not occur. Repeating this with $2$, etc., we reduce our sequence to a single sign.
How does this help calculating the multiplication in $2S_n^\pm$? Well, given any expression $\sigma$ in terms of cycles in $2S_n^\pm$, we may first multiply them in $S_n$, and express their product in terms of disjoint cycles. Lifting this normal form to $2S_n^\pm$, you have found a product $\rho$ of disjoint cycles in $2S_n^\pm$ with the same image in $S_n$. So $\sigma=\pm \rho$. To determine the sign, write $\sigma\rho^{-1}$ as product of cycles and apply the above algorithm.

In your description of marking transpositions, after "$[2,1]$", it should read "followed by a bunch of transpositions that do not move 1"? (as opposed to 2)

Should there be a minus sign in your first bullet point? It seems to me that $[1,i][k,l] = [1,i]^-1[k,l][1,i][1,i] = [k,l]^{[1,i]}[1,i]$? (This seems to be independent of whether we work in $2S_n^+$ or $2S_n^-$)

Yes to both points (sorry, in a previous comment I had misread one of your remarks)
